# How to drop sentences that are too long in Huggingface?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I'm going through the [Huggingface tutorial](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3/3?fw=pt) and it appears as the library has automatic `truncation`, to cut sentences that are too long, based on a max value, or other things.

How can I remove sentences for the same reasoning (sentences are too long, based on a max value, etc), instead of truncating them? e.g., if the sentence is too long, drop it.

**Example for truncation:**

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

checkpoint = "distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
sentence_input = 'this is an input'

result = tokenizer(sentence_input, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
```

**Example to prepare samples in a batch**

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, DataCollatorWithPadding

raw_datasets = load_dataset("glue", "mrpc")
checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)


def tokenize_function(example):
    return tokenizer(example["sentence1"], example["sentence2"], truncation=True)


tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [filter](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/process#select-and-filter) is all you need:

```py
import pandas
from datasets import Dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

df = pandas.DataFrame([{"sentence1": "bla", "sentence2": "bla"}, {"sentence1": "bla "*600, "sentence2": "bla"}])
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)


checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

#Not truncating the samples allows us to filter them
def tokenize_function(example):
    return tokenizer(example["sentence1"], example["sentence2"])


tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
print(len(tokenized_datasets))
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.filter(lambda example: len(example['input_ids']) <= tokenizer.max_model_input_sizes[checkpoint])
print(len(tokenized_datasets))
```

Output:

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (1205 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
2
1
```

Comment: Hmm but this wouldn't work with padding right?

Comment: No, it won't (I thought it isn't required because you mentioned `DataCollatorWithPadding`).  To also handle padding, I would use `tokenizer.tokenize()` and filter the created column. After that, I would use `tokenize_function` with that new column and the parameter `is_split_into_words=True`.